# Unable to receive object in web api when making ajax calls via AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

[image]Hi I am developing one small web api application. Since 2 days I am struggling with small problem. I am not able t receive object in web api methods. For example, below is my web api method,

```
 public IHttpActionResult Put(int id, NCT_UserRegistration users)
        {
        }
```

And I am making ajax call as below.

```
 this.update = function (sub) {
        var url = '/NCT_Users/' + sub.user_id;
        return $http({
            method: 'put',
            data: JSON.stringify(sub),
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
    }
```

In the above Put method I am able to receive Id but I am not able to get values . It always receives null.
This is my object.

```
var sub = {
            User_EmailId: $scope.User_EmailId,
            User_Password: $scope.User_Password,
            User_Name: $scope.User_Name,
            User_MobileNum: $scope.User_MobileNum,
            User_Status: $scope.User_Status,
            User_Role: $scope.User_Role,
            User_CreatedDate: new Date(),
            User_UpdatedDate: new Date()
        };
```

This is header request from browser.

```
URL:http://localhost:22045/NCT_Users/1
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:[::1]:22045
Response Headers
view source
```

Request Header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:content-Type, accept, origin, X-Requested-With, Authorization, name
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, PUT, DELETE, GET,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:130
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 24 Jan 2017 10:50:12 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?RjpcTmlyYW5qYW5cTm9vckNvbnN1bHRpbmdTb2x1dGlvblxOb29yQ29uc3VsdGluZ1xOb29yQ29uc3VsdGluZ1xOQ1RfVXNlcnNcMQ==?=
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:145
Content-type:application/json
Host:localhost:22045
Origin:http://localhost:22045
Referer:http://localhost:22045/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

In POST method also object holds null always. My get and delete methods works fine. I am facing problems only with the objects. I am trying to figure out from morning. May I get some help on this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. Whenever i make request such as post or put my object doesnt hold any value.

Comment: I am sorry. I have observed as below. Request URL:http://localhost:22045/NCT_Users/1
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:[::1]:22045
Response Headers
view source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to stringify, Angular makes it work internally

```
this.update = function (sub) {
        var url = '/NCT_Users/' + sub.user_id;
        return $http({
            method: 'put',
            data: sub,
            url: url,
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I removed and checked. Still same issue. I have attached screenshot in my question.

Comment: did you check your request body?

Comment: Yes. This is request payload. {"User_EmailId":"dsd","User_Name":"sdsd","User_CreatedDate":"2017-01-24T10:54:23.849Z","User_UpdatedDate":"2017-01-24T10:54:23.849Z","user_id":1}

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881246/posting-from-angular-to-net-webapi-is-always-null

Comment: i put   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }, and started working fine.

Comment: headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }